# Chromedriver not deleting scoped* dir in temp folder

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, temp

Chromedriver is not deleting the folder named scoped_* at the end of the execution.

[Chromedriver not deleting scoped* dir in temp folder after test is complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289035/chromedriver-not-deleting-scoped-dir-in-temp-folder-after-test-is-complete)

The above solution is not working for me, I need a python solution.

My version of google chrome is: 99.0.4844.74 64 bits
and I tried chromedriver 99.0.4844.51 and ChromeDriver 99.0.4844.35

Also tried this code at the end of every script, after driver.close() and driver.quit():

```
try:
    for f in glob.glob(r"C:\Windows\Temp\scoped_dir*"):
        shutil.rmtree(f)
except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

output:

> [WinError 5] Access is denied:
> 'C:\Windows\Temp\scoped_dir130892_1670710986\BrowserMetrics\BrowserMetrics-62347334-8E820.pma'

Also tried to run a batch file with the following code:

```
@echo off
Taskkill /IM chromedriver.exe /F 
Taskkill /IM chrome.exe /F
cd /D %Temp%
for /d %%D in (scoped_dir*) do rd /s /q "%%D"
del /f /q *
```

output:

```
SUCCESS: The process "chrome.exe" with PID 406028 has been terminated.
```

but it doesn't delete the folders.

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
[WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Windows\Temp\scoped_dir130892_1670710986\BrowserMetrics\BrowserMetrics-62347334-8E820.pma'
```

...implies that some child still continues to access *`BrowserMetrics-62347334-8E820.pma`*. Hence *`shutil.rmtree()`* fails with *WinError* as the file is still accessed by some other process.

---

### Deep Dive

Although your program is at the end of the execution but as [`@johnchen@chromium.org`](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=644#c22) mentions:

> This appears to be a race condition between ChromeDriver and Chrome. ChromeDriver creates these temp directories for use by Chrome, and at the end ChromeDriver tries to delete those directories. ChromeDriver waits for the main Chrome process to terminate before doing the deletion, but some Chrome child processes might still be running and holding on to those directories, causing the deletion to fail. Currently ChromeDriver doesn't retry the deletion. Adding some retries might be the easiest fix.

This issue was addressed through this [revision](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/7dfc58a73db333dc9b76adc2c6eb409b389a39bf) / [commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/7dfc58a73db333dc9b76adc2c6eb409b389a39bf):

> [Chromedriver] Retry deleting temp dir when needed
>
> Occasionally ChromeDriver may fail to delete temporary directories
> while exiting, causing wasted disk space. This change adds retry logic
> while cleaning up these directories.

and was available with [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) ***v2.30*** and with [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53744026/7429447) ***v99.0.4844.51*** this issue seems to be a regression.

---

### tl; dr

[WebDriver is not deleting the profile directory after test exits](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1934)

Answer (score 0):

> [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Windows\Temp\scoped_dir130892_1670710986\BrowserMetrics\BrowserMetrics-62347334-8E820.pma'

The reason why you are getting this error is because windows doesn't allow that python script from altering files that are in the **C:\Windows** folder. Even with being the administrator account, you are going to have to run the file as an administrator. You can do this by right-clicking on the .py file and clicking on `Run as administrator`. This will allow the script to alter the files in the **C:\Windows** directory.

If denial of access persists, take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091530/permissionerror-winerror-5-access-is-denied-python-using-moviepy-to-write-gif). Another solution to this problem might be to install **pydirectory**.

Answer (score 0):

We also have been having this issue. A developer recently discovered that for us it could be due to a method which was recently added to kill Chrome Driver process where the `Driver.Quit()` did not exit properly. The method was executed before the `Driver.Quit()` which could have caused `Driver.Quit()` or `Driver.Close(0)` to not be executed correctly.

This was only tested locally so far and not in a pipeline; however, early results show this resolved the `scoped_dir` files from being left behind.

Hope this helps someone as we searched online a lot for solutions and even scripted cleanup to run whenever chrome processes were not running each hour.